# Найти сумму числел из строки с помощью Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Необходимо реализовать метод , который должен возвращать сумму целых значений из
списка строк.

```
myMethod(Arrays.asList("2 плюс 2","2019 год был самым лучшим"));
```

На выходе 2023 соответственно. Прошу помощи,все до чего додумался это преобразовать в стрим из чаров и работать с ним,но дальше не продвинулся

Делал примерно так:

```
return input.
                stream()
                .map(e -> e.toCharArray())
                .flatMap(e -> CharBuffer.wrap(e).chars().mapToObj(ch -> (char)ch))
                .filter(e -> Character.isDigit(e))
```

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что требуется. Можете пожалуйста добавить пример(ы): `ввод` `вывод` . Из примера приведенного в вопросе мне ничего не понятно: как из `"2 плюс 2","2019 год был самым лучшим"` можно получить `2023`?

Comment: `2 + 2 + 2019` как я понял необходимо найти все числа в строке и сложить их.

Comment: Артур прав,выбрать все числа из строки и найти их сумму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если считать, что все числа ограждены пробелами, то задача сводится к:

- получить массив "слов",
- отфильтровать не являющиеся числами
- сложить оставшиеся

то есть, например так:

```
private static boolean canConvertStrToInt(final String str){
    try{
        Integer.parseInt(str);  // пробуем преобразовать
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){ // неважно, почему не получилось
        return false; // вернем "нельзя преобразовать"
    }
}

public static int sumIntsInStrings(List<String> inputValues){
    return inputValues.stream()
            .flatMap(str-> Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))) // разбиваем на слова. Если нужны не только пробелы - regexp нужно поменять
            .filter(Main::canConvertStrToInt) // убираем не числовые значения
            .map(Integer::parseInt)// преобразуем в Stream<Integer>
            .flatMapToInt(IntStream::of)// в IntStream
            .sum();  // и суммируем.
}
```